# How to get Firebase Messages Token Synchronously

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the last Firebase version, this method is deprecated

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

Is there any new function that I can use to get token synchronously?

Important: onNewToken() method does not work for me

Comment: Google just likes to create headache for Android developers...  Half of our time is just spent on addressing Google's ad hoc requirements every now and then!